# Difference between int someInts[3] and int* someInts = new int[3]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, declaration

What is the difference between declaring  a new integer array by using `int someInts[3]`, versus using `int* someInts = new int[3]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 main differences:

1. The first will allocate a memory on the stack, that will be unavailable once the function returns.
   The second will allocate a memory on the freestore, which will be available until deleted.
2. The first `someInts` is an array of ints, you cannot assign new address to it.
   The second is a pointer to int, so you may assign a new address to it.

Comment: Depending on your perspective, it may not be helpful to distinguish between "stack" and "heap", as these are not concepts that the C++ language concerns itself with.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Thanks for the comment. What term would you use to point out the first difference I mentioned?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth On the contrary the RAII idiom is a huge concern of the c++ design.  And to say that the the freestore is not a R in RAII is disingenious.

Comment: Take a look at @Jerry's answer.  The keywords are "automatic" and "allocated" (these are known as "storage durations").

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: RAII is of course an important concept in modern C++.  But it has nothing to do with the terms "stack" vs. "heap"; the language standard doesn't concern itself with these implementation-specific details.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the language standard language is not a valid retort. It is a useful mind model. and quite close to the actual inner workings of the c++ programs we encounter.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I don't really understand your point.  When learning C++ it is better to concern yourself with the model that the language is based on, rather than the underlying implementation details.  The model is that variables can have different lifetimes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The language in the standard is not a good starting point for conceptual models.   Bjarne frequently uses stack and freestore as arguments for the c++ design. Compiler dependent details is of course not the point here, but rather the image the concepts provokes.

Answer (score 3):

The difference that's generally important (especially when you're dealing with something other than `int`s) is that with when you use the latter (`int *someints = new int[3];`) you have to explicitly delete the data when you're done using it.

Most of the time, you want to use `std::vector<int> someints(3);` instead. This will (normally) allocate the space for the data similarly, *but* it'll automatically delete that space when the variable goes out of scope (including, for example, leaving the scope via an exception being thrown, which is much more difficult to handle correctly when you allocate/free the memory manually).

Comment: +1: First answer that manages to explain the difference without referring to implementation-specific detail (stack vs. heap).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `int* someInts = new int[3]` allocates the memory on the heap. Declaring `int someInts[3]` allocates it on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

When you do someInts[3], you allocate memory on the stack, this means that it will delete itself (good) but if you want to access after the function has ended you'll run into trouble as it will already have been deleted. IE:

```
int* returnPointerThingy(){
    int someInts[3];
    someInts[0] = 3;
    someInts[1] = 2;
    someInts[2] = 1;
    return someInts
}
```

This will return a null pointer since someInts has been deleted. If you try to access something in someInts god help you.

If this is similar to what you which to do you want to use the `new` keyword. It will allow you to allocate something on the "Heap" and it will live after the function it was declared in has ended. Thus this:

```
int* returnPointerThingy(){
    int* someInts = new int[3];
    someInts[0] = 3;
    someInts[1] = 2;
    someInts[2] = 1;
    return someInts
}
```

Will not return a null pointer and you will be able to use the values stored by someInts. However this comes with a drawback, you must delete someInts like this:

```
delete [] someInts
```

So you don't end up with memory leaks, when the heap gets taken up by pointers and such.

It depends on your situation for which to use as both are better in their own situations.